# JavaScript onclick function only works once (very simple code)

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onclicklistener

I know there are many topics about this, but they address some variable issue. Mine is much more simple, but it is not working. Only works once.

```js
var bt1;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load);

function load() {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div>welcome</div>';
  bt1 = document.getElementById('bt1');
  bt1.onclick = clicked;
}

function clicked() {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div>welcome</div>';
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="bt1">Click me</button>
</body>
```

I tried taking the `clicked` function in and out of the `onclick` statement (as some other topics suggested).

I also tried moving the `bt1` variable declaration around (and not using a variable at all).

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you assign to the `innerHTML` of a container (even if you're just concatenating with existing HTML), the container's contents will be *removed*, and the new `innerHTML` *string* will be parsed and then rendered by the browser. So, listeners that used to be attached to anything inside of the container will no longer work.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('#container');
const child = container.children[0];

// Before: the child's parent is the `container`, as expected:
console.log(child.parentElement);

container.innerHTML += '';

// After: the child has no parent element!
// If a listener was attached to the child before,
// the child will no longer even be in the document!
console.log(child.parentElement);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>child</div>
</div>
```

For what you're doing, either use `insertAdjacentHTML`, which will *not* corrupt listeners, but will perform similar functionality to `innerHTML +=`:

```js
var bt1;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load);
function load() {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div>welcome</div>';
  bt1 = document.getElementById('bt1');
  bt1.onclick = clicked;
}

function clicked() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div>welcome</div>');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="bt1">Click me</button>
</body>
```

Or, explicitly create the new element to append, and use `appendChild`:

```js
var bt1;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load);
function load() {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div>welcome</div>';
  bt1 = document.getElementById('bt1');
  bt1.onclick = clicked;
}

function clicked() {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = 'welcome';
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="bt1">Click me</button>
</body>
```

Comment: And why when I insert `bt1.onclick = clicked;` again right after I do the `innerHTML +=` it is not re-adding the listener? EDIT: nevermind, I added the `getElementById` again too and it worked.

Comment: You would have to explicitly tell the interpreter to re-add the listener, for the listener to be re-added -eg, select `btn1` again and use `bt1.onclick = clicked;`

Answer (score 0):

Another quick fix would be to reattach the listener in clicked mehtod.

```js
var bt1;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', load);

function load() {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div>welcome</div>';
  bt1 = document.getElementById('bt1');
  bt1.onclick = clicked;
}

function clicked(a) {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div>welcome</div>';
  bt1 = document.getElementById('bt1');
  bt1.onclick = clicked;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button id="bt1">Click Me</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Apparently you can do this.

```
    app = document.getElementById("my_dummy_app");

    function start() {
        // get your element inside of wrapper element that you want 
        // to change its html content
        button = document.getElementById("button_inside_of_app");
        button.addEventListener("event", () => {
            app.innerHTML = // some html
        })        
        // then restart your function so 'button' will defined again
        // we do this because we changed dom and now we need to 
        // assign our button to its element again
        start()
    }

    start()
```

or this

```
    app = document.getElementById("my_dummy_app");

    function start(root) {
        // get your element inside of wrapper element that you want 
        // to change its html content
        button = document.getElementById("button_inside_of_app");
        button.addEventListener("event", () => {
            root.innerHTML = // some html
        })
        // then restart your function so 'button' will defined again
        // we do this because we changed dom and now we need to 
        // assign our button to its element again
        start(app)
    }

    start(app)
```

edit: on second look, it's an infinite loop

Comment: This seems completely unrelated the problem. Did you mean to post the answer to a different question?

Comment: @Bergi Hello Bergi! No this answer is in the right place actually. The thing is at the time I posted, I didn't have much time, so I just copy pasted one of my n project codes. Every time you change the innerHTML of "wrapper element", the elements inside of that "wrapper" actually changes, in other words DOM changes. So you can wrap the whole code in a function -- you need to define your html element in that function, and when you changed wrapper's innerHTML, you can start it over. It's not best practice but at that moment it came to my mind.

Comment: and other codes in this post will work, until you don't want to "inject" any html, but you need to change the whole innerHTML to something else. So here is a simple idea for anybody who wants that.

Comment: Thanks, your comment makes sense, but the code in the answer does not. What is `ROOT`, what is `App`, what is `Panel`, what is `todoArray`, and where are the `.input-complete` elements defined? If you find the time, please [edit] your post